# Limit the number of results retrieved from Neo4J by counting the total number of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J cypher request of the following kind that I use in my app:

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user='6dbe5450-852d-11e4-9c48-b552fc8c2b90')
WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO' WITH rel MATCH (ctx:Context) WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid 
RETURN
DISTINCT STARTNODE(rel).uid AS source_id, STARTNODE(rel).name AS source_name,
ENDNODE(rel).uid AS target_id, ENDNODE(rel).name AS target_name, rel.uid AS edge_id, 
ctx.name AS context_name, rel.statement AS statement_id, rel.weight AS weight;
```

It returns 112 rows, which are relationships between the nodes, as well as the context where each relationship appears and the statement where it occurred.

I know that I can limit the number of rows I get in this table using `LIMIT 50`.

However, what I need to do  is to automatically sort the rows in such a way, that I only get 50 most frequently mentioned nodes, which can be **both** in `source_name` and in `target_name` columns.

So what I need to do is to count how many of each kind of node I have both in `source_name` and in `target_name`, collect them, and only display the top frequently mentioned 50 of them.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user='6dbe5450-852d-11e4-9c48-b552fc8c2b90')
WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO' WITH rel MATCH (ctx:Context) WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid 
UNWIND [startnode(rel),endnode(rel)] as node
RETURN node.uid, node.name
       collect([rel.uid AS edge_id, rel.statement AS statement_id, rel.weight AS weight,
       ctx.name AS context_name]) as aggregated_data, 
       count(*)
ORDER BY count(*) desc limit 50;
```

Comment: I get an error on UNWIND using 2.0.1 - I see it's a new feature since 2.0.4, so is there any possibility to do the same but with another operator? Thanks!